# Grails - Link checking as part of a continuous integration

Tags: grails, continuous-integration, hudson, link-checking

So, we have a grails app set up with a Hudson CI build process. We're running unit tests, integration tests, and about to set up Selenium for some functional tests as well.

However, are there any good ways of fully testing a sites links to make sure nothing has broken in a release.

I know there's link checkers in general, but I'd like to have it be a part of the build process, so a build outright fails if something isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up using was a command line program called linkchecker that we could install by apt-get and we ran from within our build script.

Answer (score 0):

WebTest has a verifyLinks step you could use: http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/verifyLinks.html

You could install the webtest plugin (it should play nice with Selenium) and just have a single test that checks links.

cheers

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I'm using selenium plugin (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Seleniumhq+Plugin) with test recorded from both developers and functional people. We start the new instance of the Grails app from the Hudson build with  the Postbuild (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)